# How do I align the bullets to middle in a <li> tag?

Tags: html, css

So I want to create a bar like that. I found a code about it and I modified it a little bit, originally it was a timeline. So my problem is that I can't align the bullets to middle in the li tag. How could I achive that?

```css
ul.language-bar {
        max-width: 29em;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 18px;
        height: 2em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 10px;
        /* change font size only to scale*/
    }

    ul.language-bar li {
        width: 15%;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
    }

    ul.language-bar li.empty:before {
        background: #fff;
        border: 0.3em solid #f98d9c;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    ul.language-bar li:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background: #f98d9c;
        width: 2em;
        height: 2em;
        border-radius: 2em;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .language-container .language-bar {
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<div class="language-container">
  <ul class="language-bar">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="empty"></li>
    <li class="empty"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add these three lines to your `ul.language-bar li:before` class

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -1em;
```

This will

1. unbind bullets to make it possible to position them directly
2. move every bullet to the center of its parent li (since it is the first parent element having `positions:relative`)
3. shift every bullet 1em (half of bullet's width) to the left to make it perfectly centred.

```css
ul.language-bar {
        max-width: 29em;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 18px;
        height: 2em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 10px;
        /* change font size only to scale*/
    }

    ul.language-bar li {
        width: 15%;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
    }

    ul.language-bar li.empty:before {
        background: #fff;
        border: 0.3em solid #f98d9c;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    ul.language-bar li:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background: #f98d9c;
        width: 2em;
        height: 2em;
        border-radius: 2em;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -1em;
    }

    .language-container .language-bar {
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<div class="language-container">
  <ul class="language-bar">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="empty"></li>
    <li class="empty"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @AME you're welcome. please accept the answer if it helped. this is a nice way to say thank you on SA and also to help community to understand the status of the question.

Comment: I know I just couldn't do it yet because you were too fast. :)

Answer (score 1):

By not trying to center an absolutely positioned pseudo element, like you're currently doing.

You will have to nest a block element inside of the `li` element and center that.

Like so:

```css
ul.language-bar {
        max-width: 29em;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 18px;
        height: 2em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 10px;
        /* change font size only to scale*/
    }

    ul.language-bar li {
        width: 15%;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
    }

    ul.language-bar li.empty span {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #fff;
        border: 0.3em solid #f98d9c;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 2em;
        height: 2em;
        border-radius: 2em;
        z-index: 2;
    }


    ul.language-bar li span {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #f98d9c;
        width: 2em;
        height: 2em;
        border-radius: 2em;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .language-container .language-bar {
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<div class="language-container">
  <ul class="language-bar">
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li class="empty"><span></span></li>
    <li class="empty"><span></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is obviously quick and dirty to illustrate the point and would need to be optimized.

Another possibility would be to use Flexbox for the layout. Still, it needs a separate element inside of the `li` elements to work.

Answer (score 1):

With some changes for a shorter CSS...

```css
:root {
  --scale: 20px;
}
.language-container  {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.language-container ul {
  list-style     : none;
  font-size      : var(--scale);
}
.language-container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #f98d9b;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
}
.language-container ul li.empty:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.3em;
  top: 0.3em;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  border-radius: 1.4em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="language-container">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="empty"></li>
    <li class="empty"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```